# advanced query mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to query a table in mongo by using multiple keys. I have been able to use the `$in` function to pull results utilizing the cmd.

I have also been successful at making mongojs play nice with node and query the database when I inject the json object that represents the query into the `find()` method. Here is that code that works.

```
db.collection(req.params.collection).find({"labels":{"$in":["key1","key2"]}}) //json injected
```

When I try to inject the json object into the `find()` method directly I get zero results.

`{"labels":{"$in":["key1","key2"]}}` is the exact json object created by the server and used by the method above.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + newQ + ")"));
console.log(json);
db.collection(req.params.collection).find(json)  //same json object as above.
```

Im lost on this one. I need to be able to dynamically set the json object and insert into the `find` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert your JSON to a string before sending it to mongodb. The find command accepts native JSON as its query parameter.

Are you using the node native driver?

Comment: Wow all of that trouble just cuz a stringify method.  All I needed to do was use  var json = eval("(" + newQ + ")")  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is newQ a string? Why not just use native JSON--that's one of the beautiful things of using javascript. (You probably don't need eval at all, just build your query like you would in the mongodb shell: `var newQ = {key:"value"};` )